# Is my thought process right?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, user-input, multiplication

My assigment is to:

> precalculate the value of every possible multiplication from 1 * 1 up to 20 * 20 (that is, 2 * 1, 3 * 1, 4 * 1, and so on; followed by 2 * 2, 3 * 2, 4 * 2, etc.) before it accepts any user input, and store the values in a dictionary. It must also retrieve the value that the user request from the dictionary, rather than calculating it again.

I am thinking of either:

1. creating a 20x2 matrix or
2. creating a list that goes from 1:20.

Both options will use a for loop to precalculate the values.

We went over tuples in class, could that be applied here? And if so, how?

Please don't give me the code, unless you need it to help explain

Comment: presumably the user will input two numbers, both between 1 and 20, and you are to look up the answer in the dictionary?

Comment: You want to store all outputs to a function which takes two numbers between 1 and 20 and returns their product. So what you're looking for is a mapping between two numbers between 1 and 20 and a single number (which is their product). Logically, that is a dictionary which maps a tuple of 2 integers to another integer.

Comment: you could use [product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to easily build your whole dictionary in a single dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tuples apply here.

You don't need a matrix here, just a nested `for` loop, say one for `i` and another for `j`. In the loop you can then create a tuple key (`(i, j)`) and store the multiplication result in your dictionary under that key:

```
multiplications[(i, j)] = i * j
```

or even

```
multiplications[i, j] = i * j
```

as the parenthesis are optional here.

After taking user input, you can then look up those results:

```
result = multiplications[userinput1, userinput2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll end up using `for` loops, yes.  If you've got that idea, you're on the right track.  The piece you might be missing is that you can use a tuple as a key to a dictionary.  So something like this:

```
{(3, 4): 12}
```

Would let you store a pre-calculated value for that result.  That might get you where you need to be.